# React Native inline Styling in an if/else statement

Tags: css, react-native, if-statement

I'm trying to style one element of an if/else statement so that if that text is shown it's italic. I've tried a few variations inline and have also tried `style={styles.italic}`.

Thanks for the help in advance.

```
if (profileIncomplete) {
    subText = translations.formatString(translations['user.complete'], {
      user: user.name,
    });
```

Comment: How are you rendering the subText ?

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan <Text style={styles.subText}>{subText}</Text> the issue is the subText can be one of 3 potential outcomes and I only need this one to be italic. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the condition you can do like below using a ternary operator, so the when your condition is true it will use the subText style and other scenarios it will use the empty style.

Assume 'isItalic' is a boolean, you can also replace this with any condition

```
<Text style={isItalic ? styles.subText:{}}>{subText}</Text>
```

Comment: thanks for the point in the right direction I had to change it a bit but worked perfectly thanks!